# Does logrotate depend on cron?

Tags: cron, logrotate

in the logrotate manpage, they say:

"Normally, logrotate is run as a daily cron job".

Does that mean that logrotate uses cron (or is executed by cron)?
If so, does that mean that if I don't configure a cron job via crontab (for instance), logrotate will not work?

Answer (score 20):

You CAN run logrotate manually WITHOUT cron.

```
logrotate <configuration file>
```

However if you want to run logrotate on a *scheduled* basis, you will need a scheduling service like cron or a systemd timer.

Your package manager should create a default schedule in **/etc/cron.daily/logrotate** that runs logrotate with the default **/etc/logrotate.conf** configuration. You can also place your custom configurations in **/etc/logrotate.d/** since the default configuration has a line that include all configurations in this directory.

```
include /etc/logrotate.d
```

If you want to run logrotate with a custom schedule, you can place your cron job in **/etc/cron.d/**.

For example, this would trigger logrotate using /etc/custom-logrotate.conf configuration every day at two o'clock.

```
0 2 * * * root /usr/sbin/logrotate /etc/custom-logrotate.conf
```

Checkout [crontab guru](https://crontab.guru/) if you need help with cron expression.

Newer distributions of Linux have systemd and utilise logrotate.timer
service which by default runs logrotate daily at `00:00`. **/etc/cron.daily/logrotate** has this at the top, skipping cron in favor of systemd timer:

```bash
# skip in favour of systemd timer
if [ -d /run/systemd/system ]; then
    exit 0
fi
```

In both cases, **/etc/logrotate.d** is by default monitored to be run daily.

Note that it doesn't matter how many times you invoke logrotate if the config **/etc/custom-logrotate.conf** specifies a frequency smaller than the times you're invoking. Your log will rotate only when the config file's frequency requirement is met. For example, if cron is invoking logrotate every 3 hours and your config file has `daily` frequency set. Your logs will only rotate after a day.

*"Does that mean that logrotate uses cron (or is executed by cron)? If so, does that mean that if I don't configure a cron job via crontab (for instance), logrotate will not work?"* - No, logrotate is a separate executable. It can still work if you put your conf file in **/etc/logrotate.d** (runs daily) or create a systemd timer or just run it manually.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, normaly, cron executes logrotate on a daily base.
It depends on your linux distro, but the normal is to have cron running it.

You can check if have the file **/etc/cron.daily/logrotate**
If thats the case, you distro uses cron to run logrotate.

If you are using docker, this can bring some problem, currently cron doesn't run inside a container.

Comment: to clarify, if /etc/cron.daily/logrotate  exists, logrotate will run daily , perhaps at midnight?

Comment: yes. default behaviour is to logrotate at midnight.